# Transfermarkt url id scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Basically i want to create a tool that you enter the players name(as it is on transfermarkt, its fine) and it gives you a list of [teammates](https://www.transfermarkt.com/luka-modric/gemeinsameSpiele/spieler/27992). I can scrape that with beautifoulsoup. The problem is, this site has random ids for [each profile/page](https://www.transfermarkt.com/luka-modric/profil/spieler/27992). Is there a way to do it without having to scrape all of the player profiles? If not, how do i scrape the entire database? (only the page with the teammates for each player)

Comment: I assume the player-ID mapping is constant, so that you can collect the data once, put that in a dict and lookup the id for a player when you need it?

Comment: You may use the search page  (e.g.,
https://www.transfermarkt.com/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query=modric&x=0&y=0 ) and check the results in the table to get the specific page of a player

Comment: @meissner_ How do i collect all the data?(and be sure i dont omit some players)

very useful, thanks! I can just use the search url and scrape the results page.

Comment: @AdamosHadjivasiliou Well, the brute force approach would be to make a get request for all possible IDs and parse the pages that do return something to extract the player names unless you can get the data from some sort of player overview page or the like, probably what newbie mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comments, you may use the search page to extract the specific page of a player.

For instance, consider the following example.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
}


player = "Modric"
data=requests.get("https://www.transfermarkt.com/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query={}&x=0&y=0".format(player), headers=headers) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "items" })

for row in table.find_all("table", { "class" : "inline-table" }):

    hrefs = row.find("a", {"class" : "spielprofil_tooltip"})

    print("player : {}".format(hrefs['title']))
    print("url : {}".format(hrefs['href']))
```

Then, according to the results you can check for the specific player. Note that the table of the results containts more information such as `team, position, age,...` that you can use to be sure that the player is the right one